# Multiply two columns and update its value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to multiple `CQty` and `CRate` columns and update `CAmt` column with that value, by bypassing a parameter.

`CQty = CQty - @Qty` it is working fine but multiplication is not working.

How can I do it?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UPDATE_BALANCE
    @Id INT,
    @Qty INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @amt decimal = (SELECT CQty * CRate 
                            FROM Balance 
                            WHERE ID = @Id )

    UPDATE Balance 
    SET CQty = CQty - @Qty, 
        CAmt = @amt  
    WHERE ID = @Id
END
```

This is also not working:

```
UPDATE Balance 
SET CQty = CQty - @Qty, 
    CAmt = (CQty * CRate) 
WHERE ID = @Id
```

Is there any best query to do this?

Comment: Is that way not working?  It is not the best way, you can do the calculation in update statement.  Depending on data types though have to test that, may have to cast the numbers as decimals in your calculation.

Comment: Have a _computed column_ instead, to ensure data consistency! `ALTER TABLE Balance ADD CAmt AS (CQty * CRate)`, or whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: @Brad what is the best way.. can you put some query?

Comment: Couple people posted answers that match my suggestion you can use one of those

Comment: Do you need to do that?  Can't you calculate the balance when it's displayed or used as as and when you need it?  That way it's always live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating the `@Amt` prior to the adjusted quantity

Just change your `update` to this

```
Update Balance 
   set CQty = CQty - @Qty
      ,CAmt = (CQty - @Qty) * Rate
WHERE ID = @Id
```

That said, Jarlh's comment of having a computed column is 100% correct.  I would just have it `persisted`.

Comment: @DanyOC Always happy to help.  It is always the little things that get ya. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, your `DECLARE` line seems rather useless. You are just calculating a value out of field values within the same table row, without using any of your input parameter.

I think you meant to do this instead:

```sql
ALTER PROC UPDATE_BALANCE
@Id INT,
@Qty INT

AS BEGIN
  UPDATE Balance SET CQty = CQty - @Qty, CAmt = (CQty - @Qty) * CRate WHERE ID = @Id
END
```